# exporting selected rows into list in python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a text file like this small example:

small example:

```
</Attributes>
ENDI,ERT,GFTR,29
ENDI,XCV,HGJ,36
TOC,FGNH,TRYCB,3742
TOC,MVCL,KJDSFH,38799
GOF,KLJG,XZCJV,31
GOF,LKBFV,JKSDHF,18
```

I would like to select some rows and add the 4th column (those lines are comma separated) to a python list. the point is all the rows are not comma separated but the rows that I am interested in are comma separated.here is the expected output:

```
TOC = [3742, 38799]
GOF = [31, 18]
```

I made the following code in python. but does not return expected output. do you know how to fix it?

```
TOC = []
GOF = []
file = open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("TOC"):
            TOC.append(line[3])
        if line.startswith("GOF"):
            GOF.append(line[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TOC = []
GOF = []
file_name = 'file.txt'

with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        if(line[0:3] == "TOC"):
            # Splits lines by commas
            line_parts = line.split(',')
            #Trims new line off wanted value.
            value = line_parts[3].replace('\n', '')
            TOC.append(value)
        elif(line[0:3] == "GOF"):
            # Splits lines by commas
            line_parts = line.split(',')
            #Trims new line off wanted value.
            value = line_parts[3].replace('\n', '')
            GOF.append(value)

print(TOC)
print(GOF)
```

This is my first time posting so I hope this helps. This should give you the result you want. If you want the values to be stored as ints replace TOC.append(value) with TOC.append(int(value)).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your solution does not work correctly is because taking the index position of a string (`line[3]`) gives you a single character. To get entire words from the comma separated line you need to [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it, specifying a comma as the separator.

Split returns an array or strings, so now when you get an index value you have a string from that position in the array, not just a character.

Here's an alternative implementation, building on WebScrapingPancake's answer, using a dictionary of lists. Using a dictionary means you don't need to know what the fist 'word' of the line is.

```
import collections

totals = collections.defaultdict(list)
file_name = 'file.txt'

with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        line_parts = line.split(',')
        # Trims new line off wanted value.
        value = line_parts[3].replace('\n', '')
        totals[line_parts[0]].append(value)

print(totals)
print(totals['TOC'])
print(totals['GOF'])
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ENDI': ['29', '36'], 'TOC': ['3742', '38799'], 'GOF': ['31', '18']})
['3742', '38799']
['31', '18']
```

The downside is you have to filter out unwanted lines, such as the first line of your file. But that's a problem I'll leave for you to solve ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSV reader. It will be helpful to you in other projects.

```
TOC = []
GOF = []
with open('file.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if len(line) == 1: # skip attribute tag
            continue
        if line[0] == "TOC":
            TOC.append(int(line[3]))
        if line[0] == "GOF":
            GOF.append(int(line[3]))
print("TOC = " + str(TOC))
print("GOF = " + str(GOF))
```

The output is:

```
TOC = [3742, 38799]
GOF = [31, 18]
```

I assume from your question that you wanted whats in the list to be ints, not string literals, so that is why the values are wrapped in int()s.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct. You just need to split the line into a list (based on comma), so that when you write `line[3]` it makes sense:

```py
TOC = []
GOF = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    line_list = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    if line.startswith("TOC"):
        TOC.append(line_list[3])
    if line.startswith("GOF"):
        GOF.append(line_list[3])
```